# Did either Captain Scarlet or Thunderbirds air an episode on UK TV that used real actors between 1998 and 2005?

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification, thunderbirds, gerry-anderson, captain-scarlet

I have some contradicting memories:

- Between 1998 and 2005, I was informed that a *Thunderbirds* episode of some sort would be airing. It would be an older episode, but with real actors this time.
- I said I wouldn't watch it.
- I remember an actor in such an episode, but it looked far more like a *Captain Scarlet* character. Very much like Colonel White at his desk.
- This was in the UK, presumably back when everyone only had BBC 1, BBC 2, ITV, Channel Four, and Channel 5.

This gives me my question: Did either Captain Scarlet or Thunderbirds air an episode on UK TV that used real actors between 1998 and 2005? Failing that, did either series, prior to 2005, ever make any television media at all that used real actors?

Comment: Could you possibly be thinking of [the live-action *Thunderbirds* film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_(2004_film)) from 2004?

Comment: There was also [a *Captain Scarlet* reboot series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerry_Anderson%27s_New_Captain_Scarlet) on ITV in 2005, but it was motion-captured CG animation rather than live action.

Comment: @F1Krazy Definitely live action.

Comment: @F1Krazy Possible, but *very* unlikely. I'm confident that it was a normal episode that was re-done with real actors.

Comment: Could it have been an episode of [UFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_(TV_series))

Comment: @RobertLongson I strongly suspect not. To my knowledge, I've never seen an episode.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but there was an attempt at an all-puppet remake/reboot/sequel series. It was intended for a 2005 release, but all we have is [this trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LoHqzKUIdY) from 2003, and a [making-of video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39A3BddHNxU) for it. I think you might enjoy it!

Comment: Though I'm not a fan of the new Scott puppet.

Comment: *"back when everyone only had BBC 1, BBC 2, ITV, Channel Four, and Channel 5"* - Don't forget, some people had satellite - Sky or BSkyB or whatever it was called over here. I don't know if cable television existed for anyone in the UK at that time though - maybe through NTL or Telewest?

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern Certainly not that. As for channels, it would definitely only be the usual five.

Comment: Take a look at these lists of Anderson appearances on the BBC in that time period: https://www.gerryanderson.com/gerry-anderson-on-the-bbc-part-3-1998-to-2001/ and https://www.gerryanderson.com/gerry-anderson-on-the-bbc-part-4-2002-to-2014/ - see if anything rings a bell. Maybe someone heard something about this potential Joe 90 remake: https://www.gerryanderson.com/fab-facts-joe-90-was-considered-for-a-live-action-movie/

Comment: Then, there's "Blunderbirds" - *"Broadcast across 1989 on the now-cancelled Our Place, this multi-part satire was a redub of Season 2's Atlantic Inferno."* However, I doubt it was aired outside Australia, and the new actors were only providing voice acting and new lines for the puppets. Youtube links to some of the parts exist, but the only one I can fid that's not bloked in the UK is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjcjrqNcEac

Comment: Ridiculously long shot, but one series of *Super Sentai* had a rescue theme, and it was broadcast in the right time frame: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/KyukyuSentaiGoGoV

Comment: Could you have misremembered an episode of Anderson's live action show [Space: 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space:_1999)? There's a low-res shot of the Series 1 cast [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:S99Cast.jpg). There was also a one-off short filmed in 1999 at a sci-fi convention, see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CywSnlVmja0). Series 1 and 2 looked a bit different from each other. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmF_GquotUM) shows Commander Koenig at his desk at 0:47.

Comment: Following on from what @RobertLongson said, here's some photos of UFO's Commander Straker looking a *little* like Colonel White: https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/23/58453.jpg and https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/gerryanderson/images/9/9d/Straker_(flight_path).png

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern I'm very confident that it's not Space: 1999 or UFO.

Comment: Two questions: Was there by any chance a biplane in it, maybe like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Tiger_Moth)? And was it 100% live action, or a show with some live action scenes and some puppet/model-shot scenes?

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern I recall not planes. I presume it was 100% live action.

Comment: I think the biplane was only part of it, mainly in scenes near the end. And are you sure about "not planes", as this would mean Thunderbirds 1 and 2, plus Fireflash and others, would not have been able to appear in it.

Answer (score 5):

There was a Thunderbirds FAB stage show with live actors playing the parts. It featured characters from Thunderbirds and Captain Scarlet. With a cast of 2 playing all the parts.  It toured for years.

Maybe it was televised, or maybe you are misremembering it coming to a local theatre near you.

Comment: Don't think it's this. I'm certain that it was an pre-existing episode, remade with real actors, and then televised.

Comment: I *think* the Captain Scarlet characters only came in when it became "Thunderbirds FAB: The Next Generation". I could be wrong.

Comment: I wish there were videos or DVDs of this - I never did get to see it live!

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern, I've never seen the show, but from what I heard the original run  contained the following exchange:  CAPTAIN SCARLET: You can't let the bomb explode, it will kill millions. CAPTAIN BLACK: Frankly, Scarlet, I don't give a damn.

Comment: @Pete In spite of OP believing it's not this, I think honestly some part of the FAB TNG stage show would be a very good fit - maybe some clips from it or an interview with the creators were shown on TV? I'm thinking of emailing the people who made it to see if they can shed any light. Though I doubt the equivalent of a full episode was ever screened.

Comment: I've been listening to episodes [9](https://www.gerryandersonpodcast.com/episode/pod-9-new-captain-scarlet-himself-wayne-forester-from-thunderbirds-fab-to-firestorm), [75](https://www.gerryandersonpodcast.com/episode/pod-75-thunderbirds-fab-with-gavin-robertson) and [76](https://www.gerryandersonpodcast.com/episode/pod-76-thunderbirds-fab-stage-show-with-gavin-robertson-part-2) of the Gerry Anderson Podcast, which feature interviews with ex-cast-members of the stage show. In ep 76, Gavin Robertson says that a TNG performance *WAS* filmed for DVD, but he decided it was a bad idea and vetoed 1/

Comment: it. No DVD/video/Blu-Ray has ever been released, and Gavin says on the episode that he thinks it was the right decision to block it. So this is looking less likely than I thought.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern I've been speaking to my dad. He says that there WERE some clips broadcast, likely as part of coverage on BBC News or some "magazine programme". He definitely remembered details such as the Thunderbirds on the actors' heads which fit in with it being this. If I was OP, I'd be accepting this answer right now.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might have been an episode of "Turbocharged Thunderbirds". It was a series of remakes of thirteen of the original episodes, alternating repeatedly in-episode between live-action and redubbed footage from that week's original episode.

I *deeply* apologise for posting this video of Episode 6:

That said, this was screened in 1994/1995, which doesn't line up with the 1998-2005 date range.

> I remember an actor in such an episode, but it looked far more like a Captain Scarlet character.

I wouldn't say they look like Captain Scarlet characters, but as you can see from that video, the live action cast don't look like Thunderbirds characters either.

There's an article about it [here](https://www.gerryanderson.com/turbocharged-thunderbirds/).

[Here's](https://thunderbirds.fandom.com/wiki/Turbocharged_Thunderbirds) a page from the Thunderbirds wiki.

(Incidentally, there's no mention of the "Thunderbirds F.A.B." stage show anywhere on that wiki. Very odd.)

Videos of other episodes:

Episode 3 is in a small window in this video, alongside a commentary:

(Once again, I *deeply*, *deeply* apologise for subjecting you all to this.)

I'm also wondering if you may be remembering something from another show, and your memories from that have become mixed in with this one. Remember what you said about an actor who looked "far more like a Captain Scarlet character"? Well, in *Red Dwarf* series 3 episode 4 (Bodyswap) Rimmer was wearing a green outfit which, according to Lister, made him look "like Captain Emerald". Due to the bodyswap, you could see both actors wearing that costume:

[image]

[image]

Mind you, that was screened in 1989, so unless there was a repeat it's even further out of the date range you remember.

Comment: Certainly not that *Turbocharged* abomination. If I ever saw that as a child, I'd be scarred for life. Not *Red Dwarf* either. I'm a fan of that series and I'd know if it were that.

Comment: The Secret Service used a combination of live action and puppets, useful because the plot involved a device which would shrink people to one-third normal size, so a puppet could appear alongside a real person!

Comment: As long as we're adding links to parodies, allow me to present Peter Cook and Dudley Moore in SuperThunderStingCar - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riMHp28_cqw